# react app positioning some image differently

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, mobile, positioning

this is a strange one. when I look at my application products screen some images are position differently to others and are more central. when I try and recreate this in google chrome or firebox browser with the dev tool and mobile view they are positioned correctly. its just showing this strange positioning on some images. As it is only showing as problem on my samsung s10 and not in the browsers I cant troubleshoot. any help or ideas would be appreciated.

The link to the hosted app is here and would need to be viewed on a mobile to recreate this problem, thanks

[https://webdev-davidm.github.io/E-commerce-front-end/#[![enter](https://webdev-davidm.github.io/E-commerce-front-end/#%5B!%5Benter) image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdXZE.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdXZE.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

check your browser you might need to add some libraries..not sure which one you can check this on mdn documentation